# VBA code to scan through imported text file

Tags: vba, parsing, excel

I am working on writing a little VBA code to gather some specific data from a large excel sheet. The Sheet contains an imported text file. Every few thousand rows or so the columns B,C,D read "Total","Nodal","displacements". Then a table of values follows with various values at various nodes in the beam. There are around 70-90 of these tables in around 50,000 rows of info. The text file can not be formatted any better than it is. I have a function to put into a formula to find 1 of the values. it looks like this:

```
{=index(B1:D68604,Match(1,(B1:B68604 = "Total")*(C1:C68604 = "Nodal")*(D1:D68604 = "displacements"),0)+WhichNode+1,3)}
```

... where the "whichnode" is just which point I care about. I'd like to write this in VBA with 2 boxes that pop up asking "How many nodes are there", and "Which node do you care about?" So that the code will scan the entire document, grab the displacement value I care about (whenever "Total" "Nodal" "displacements" appears in columns B,C,D, let's say I want the displacement at the 29th node - that value will always be 30 rows and the same cell as the cell containing the string "displacements"). I cannot figure out how to write the script so that it will scan through the entire excel file and grab the data from the specific cell that I want. Any guidance would be helpful!

** In response to some comments. The number of nodes changes depending on the parameters used to run the testing program - the program tests the strength of a beam until it fails depending on some input parameters. For each time phase there are roughly 58 nodes. So I normally care about the 29th node (the middle of the beam) at each time phage - 60 - 80 typically, it depends on how long it takes the beam to break. I mainly want to be able to tell the program which node to look at. Normally I care about the 29th, but sometimes I want the 2nd or 57th (near the endpoints of the beam). Does that make sense?

```
Total   Nodal   displacements   
Node    u           v         theta
1   -3.62E-10   -2.97E-09   -3.96E-03
2   -1.28E-01   -2.21E+00   -3.97E-03
3   -2.51E-01   -4.41E+00   -3.96E-03
4   -3.69E-01   -6.61E+00   -3.95E-03
5   -4.82E-01   -8.81E+00   -3.94E-03
6   -6.45E-01   -1.21E+01   -3.90E-03
```

A table like this appears a bunch of times in the excel sheet - whereever a new time phase is being entered.

There are 64 nodes, but I normally care about the 29th one (sometime I want others, that is why I want to be able to tell the VBA code to search for a specific one. I want it to grab the "v" value for whatever node I care about and bring it into another sheet so I can just focus on the "v" value for each node at each time phase as opposed to scanning through thousands of rows to get each value that I need.

Essentially I want a code that will say
If cell(i,B) = "Total" and cell(i,C) = "nodal" and cell(i,D) = "displacements" Then
Copy cell (i+1+SpecificNode,D) into another shet in a column titled "v values for node i" or something like that... Does that make sense?

Thanks for your guys' help!

Comment: Why are you asking the user *How many nodes are there* when that should be able to be reported back with a simple `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Columns(2), "Total", Columns(3), "Nodal", Columns(4), "displacements")` ?

Comment: I'm always lazy in paragraphs. Can you illustrate your data and then your expected result in its simplest form?

Answer (score 0):

Without some sample data together with the expected results, there is some guesswork to envision what you are describing. You have made no mention as to what you actually want to do with the node of data once you've found it so in my proposed solution, I'm simply reporting the range's address up to column D.

```
Sub Get_a_Node()
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long, iNODES As Long, iPICKNODE As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet4")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        iNODES = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(2), "Total", .Columns(3), "Nodal", .Columns(4), "displacements")
        iPICKNODE = Application.InputBox(Title:="Select a Valid Node", prompt:="Pick a Node between 1 and " & iNODES, _
          Default:=1, Type:=1)
        If iPICKNODE > 0 And iPICKNODE <= iNODES Then
            'You could loop until you get to the nth occurrence or use a worksheet formula like the following.
            '=SMALL(INDEX(ROW(A:A)+((Sheet4!B:B<>"Total")+(Sheet4!C:C<>"Nodal")+(Sheet4!D:D<>"displacements"))*1E+99,,),1)
            fr = Application.Evaluate("SMALL(INDEX(ROW(1:" & lr & ")+(('" & .Name & "'!B1:B" & lr & "<>""Total"")+" & _
              "('" & .Name & "'!C1:C" & lr & "<>""Nodal"")+('" & .Name & "'!D1:D" & lr & "<>""displacements""))*1E+99,,)," & iPICKNODE & ")")
            MsgBox "you picked Node " & iPICKNODE & " at " & .Cells(fr, 1).Resize(iPICKNODE + 1, 4).Address(0, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

That seems to resolve your immediate problem of locating and reporting the nth node of data. What you do with it after the fact will be up to you.